# What is the best data structure for a generic step function?

Tags: c++, data-structures, computational-geometry

I need to implement a step function (i.e. piecewise constant).  There are a few requirements that it will need to have.

1. It will have to be evaluated repeatedly at random locations, then evaluated sequentially over an interval.
2. It Will have to be easily updated, i.e. adding an increase/decrease over an interval.

So my question is what is the best data structure for this sort of thing?  I was thinking that due to the random access nature a Binary tree is the most likely, but I'm hoping I'm not missing something.  Also is there a good implementation already out there for C++.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).  A Computational Geometry expert might have a better idea.  (I am assuming you mean a "piecewise constant" function, by the way, not a "step function".  If that is correct, I suggest updating your question.)

Comment: @Nate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: Yes this will have thousands of domain values.

Comment: A binary tree is what you need. @Nemo: no need for segment tree, the intervals here are non-overlapping.

Comment: @ybungalobill:  I always thought "step function" referred to Nate's definition.  Apparently I was wrong, but "piecewise constant" is still a better term for this, IMO.

Comment: @Nemo: segment tree states that it cannot be modified once created and I will be modifying it regularly. About 1000 reads to a modification, but with millions of modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since the intervals cannot overlap, binary tree is the right data structure. If you did not need fast updates, it could be as simple as having a sorted sequence of the interval endpoints; querying the function value at a certain location could be done using, for example, one of the STL binary search methods `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`, evaluating over a range using two searches. However, for fast updates a self-balancing binary tree is naturally better.

The standard library does define a container with tree-like access: `std::map` (although it is not required to be implemented using a binary tree, it usually is).

for completeness, it should be mentioned that [Boost ICL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) library has an `interval_map`, a `std::map`-like container that uses intervals as keys and with *aggregate on overlap* insertion semantics.

Comment: The Boost ICL is ideal for what the problem that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I'd expect slightly higher overhead from ICL on insertion, compared to using std::map, since it needs to deal with overlaps. Query times are probably comparable although I've never timed that. ICL is definitely more straightforward for your problem.

Comment: I'm willing to accept a little overhead for a lot of programming saving.  The kicker was the aggregation in the interval map.  I'll be adding or subtracting 1 from an entire interval at a time, and interval_map makes this trivial to implement.  In fact it is one of their trivial examples.